# How to solve this probability problem? I did try my solution but I don't know if it's correct

Tags: probability

I have this probability problem that I need to check if my solution is correct

12 products were made, of which 8 are of excellent quality. 9 products were selected at random. What is the probability that there are at least 5 of them, but no more than 7 of excellent quality?

I used the binomial law to solve it, but i'm not sure if that's the only way to solve it.

Here is my solution for it

https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/611334873176604733/698512345076596807/unknown.png

Comment: How did you get $p=0.6$? I would assume $p=8/12=2/3$.

Comment: @Fakemistake p = 2/3 which roughly equals to 0.666666

Comment: You are selecting $9$ out of $12$. The hypergeometric distribution is the way to go: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution

Comment: Are you choosing with or without replacement?  The way I read the problem, you pick $9$ out of the $12$, so no replacement.

Comment: @lulu  that i don't know,  i think yes

Comment: Well, it changes the problem dramatically.  If you really have no idea which is intended, then I suggest you solve it both ways.

Answer (score 0):

There are only 4 products of low quality, so a priori at least 5 of the 9 picked products are of excellent quality. So your probability $P$ is equal to
$$
P=1-\textrm{P}(8 \textrm{ are of excellent quality})=1-\frac{4\cdot 1}{\binom{12}{9}}=1-\frac{1}{55}
$$

**Remark** In this answer I assumed that 4 product are low quality

Comment: This answer is if we have 4 certain low quality products. But the question was we have 3 estimates, we can either have 4, 3 or 2 low quality products

Comment: ... or 1 or 0 low quality product?. And any of these option with equal probability?This should be specified in the text

Comment: it was specified. 
"What is the probability that there are at least 5 of them, but no more than 7 of excellent quality?"
so we can't have less than 5 (which is obvious) and not more than 7 of excellent quality

Comment: It was specified that IN THE SAMPLE of 9, at least 5 and no more than 7, were of excellent quality. It was not specified that in the whole set of 12 products, more than 8 could be of excellent quality.  Saying "12 products were made, of which 8 are of excellent quality" is VERY misleading. Should say "12 products were made, of which AT LEAST 8 are of excellent quality"